# Laravel trailing url after Auth::logout();

Tags: php, laravel

**Problem**

after running this code in my controller

```
public function logout()
{
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

it works perfectly BUT it leaves this url..`http://localhost:8000/test#` obviously i dont want it to say `/test#` at the end

**Question**

Whats causing this to appear at the end of my url and how do i resolve it?

Comment: Can it be that your project is in webroot under a folder named test? which is then the webroot for laravel defined by "/" ;)

Comment: are you using a javascript framework?

Comment: @ReneM. The page im logging out from is '/test' in my routes, its a default  laravel build.

Comment: @EddyTheDove Not sure if jquery counts

Comment: from where did you logged out? button click? Could you post the html code that triggers logout?

Comment: It looks weird, surely it's something except your laravel, go for jQuery codes

Comment: @PaladiN Found the problem, `data-toggle="ajaxModal"` caused it to save the url after redirect for some reason which is weird..

Comment: `#` usually comes from Javascript.